# Replicate TypeScripts 'as' with Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In TypeScript I can do something like this

```
interface LoginInterface {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

const MyObject = {
  credentials: null as LoginInterface,
  otherInfo: "I'm something not relevant to this question"
}
```

Basically I have defined an interface `LoginInterface` then I have created a variable `MyObject` which is an object with many properties (only two in this case), one of those properties `credentials` needs to have a default value of `null` but I want to declare that it is of type `LoginInterface`, with TypeScript it is very simple as I can use the keyword `as`.  How could I replicate this using [Flow](https://flow.org/en/)?

Now I know I can do something like this

```
const MyObject: {
  credentials: LoginInterface,
  otherInfo: string
} = {
  credentials: null,
  otherInfo: "I'm something not relevant to this question"
};
```

But I don't want to define a type for `MyObject` I just want to define the type for the property `credentials` of `MyObject`, similar to how I can achieve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow definitely won't allow this, because it's not type-safe. One of the big reasons for using Flow is to prevent null-pointer errors.

To be explicit that the value is `null` but *could* be a `LoginInterface`, you'll need to tell Flow that the value has type `?LoginInterface`, which is the same as `null | LoginInterface`.

If you really can't do that with a named type, you can do it inline with:

```
const MyObject = {
  credentials: (null: ?LoginInterface),
  otherInfo: "I'm something not relevant to this question"
}
```

You need the parentheses, so that Flow can separate the type expressions from the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the quick straight forward answer!